# How to execute "Debug As" -> "Maven Build" Programmatically in Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I would like to execute programmatically "Debug As" -> "Maven Build", from my eclipse plugin. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You use the Eclipse Launch services. This is described extensively in the Eclipse Help in 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide' > 'Programmer's Guide' > 'Program Launch and Debug Support'

Comment: Thank you so much Greg! That is it... But how can I find the launch "Maven Build" ID?

Comment: You will have to examine the maven plug-ins to find out what they declare. Or maybe look at an existing .launch file.

Comment: Thank you, In Debug Configurations -> Right Click on Debug Profile -> Export...
I got the .lauch file. It seems to have all information I need. I will try to keep this post updated as soon as I perform tests.